# JQuery mobile panel

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, panel

I'm fairly new to jquery and I'm wanting to use the panel feature, however my code isn't really working. I copied most of it from: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/ just to test and the panel is taking over the whole screen and the close button isn't working and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h3>
                    Test
                </h3>
                <a href="#menu-panel"class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="bars">Menu</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-theme="a" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="push" id="menu-panel">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" class="nav-search">
                <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Accordion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">AJAX Navigation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Autocomplete</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Buttons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Checkboxes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Collapsibles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Controlgroup</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Dialogs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Fixed toolbars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Flip switch toggle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Footer toolbar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Form elements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Grids</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Header toolbar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Icons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Listviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Loader overlay</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Navbar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Navbar, persistent</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Pages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Popup</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Radio buttons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Select</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Slider, single</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Text inputs & textarea</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Transitions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /panel -->
    </div>    
</body>
```

With script .js and .css calls in the head:

```
<script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: when you're trying to ask a question about jQuery Mobile, please consider adding it with jquery-mobile tag :)

Comment: I completely over-looked that. Thank you for the edit!

Comment: no problem :) glad to be of help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/

> "A panel must be a sibling to the header, content and footer elements
>   inside a jQuery Mobile page. You can add the panel markup either
>   before or after these elements, but not in between. **A panel cannot
>   be placed outside a page**, but this constraint will be removed in a
>   future version."

So just place the panel div within your page :)

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>
                Test
            </h3>
            <a href="#menu-panel"class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="bars">Menu</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-theme="a" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="push" id="menu-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" class="nav-search">
            <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Accordion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">AJAX Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Autocomplete</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Checkboxes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Collapsibles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Controlgroup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Dialogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Fixed toolbars</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Flip switch toggle</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Footer toolbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Form elements</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Grids</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Header toolbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Icons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Listviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Loader overlay</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Navbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Navbar, persistent</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Pages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Popup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Radio buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Select</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Slider, single</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Text inputs & textarea</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Transitions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->
    </div>

</div>    
</body>
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MQPQ/).

Comment: A panel can be added as an external .html file though.